# Open cart product page goes blank upon theme upload (vQmod on)

Tags: opencart, vqmod

Here's the scenario:
Fresh install of Open Cart. Fresh install of vQmod. Everything is working fine. But when I upload certain theme - purchased and licensed - the site has an issue. The home page is working, but the product page goes blank.

I have tried all possible combinations of OpenCart and vQmod versions (except for 2.0 for OC because the theme doesn't support it yet). I am out of ideas.

Edit: After showing all errors as adviced I finally saw the reason : "oc_product_tab' doesn't exist"

Comment: Enable error logging to see what the issue is, or look in your error logs - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/711273

Comment: Thank you Jay Gilford! That helped me alot. I turned on the error reporting and found the solution quick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. It turned out that the "Extra Product Tabs Opencart Extension" is missing. This is a standart free plugin that comes with template theme but it wasn't configured. It turnes out that  the theme works with it.

Go to system>users>user groups and select all for both access and modify. Save. Than go to Catalog menu and click on Extra product tabs. Click Insert and add the module. That’s it. It’s a standard opencart module which is free for use.

Comment: That extension is not a standard part of an opencart store. It will be part of your theme or from somewhere else. You can mark your own question as solved which will gain you reputation on the site

Comment: Unfortunately it won't gain any reputation. I answered my own questions several times (because nobody else did until I found the solution) and - surprise surprise - no reputation. Even if in many cases this was very often searched question and the answer helped many other users. But I agree that answering your own questions shouldn't give any rep otherwise we would have so many self-answered questions...