# Error on product page

Tags: php, mysql

I have installed a theme on my server, however when i click the products on the page, there is an error, shows oc_product_tab is missing,

There is an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Error: Table '2216394_huang.oc_product_tab' doesn't exist
> Error No: 1146
> SELECT t.tab_id, td.name, pt.text, t.position, t.show_empty FROM oc_product_tab pt LEFT JOIN oc_tab t ON (pt.tab_id = t.tab_id) LEFT JOIN oc_tab_description td ON (t.tab_id = td.tab_id) WHERE pt.product_id = '40' AND td.language_id = '1' AND pt.language_id = '1' AND t.status = '1' AND ( t.show_empty = '1' OR NOT pt.text REGEXP '^[[:space:]]*$' ) ORDER BY t.position, t.sort_order, td.name' in /srv/disk13/2216394/www/popularhandbags.co.uk/system/database/mysqli.php:40 Stack trace: #0 /srv/disk13/2216394/www/popularhandbags.co.uk/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_library_db.php(20): DBMySQLi->query('SELECT t.tab_id...') #1 /srv/disk13/2216394/www/popularhandbags.co.uk/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_model_catalog_product.php(620): DB->query('SELECT t.tab_id...') #2 /srv/disk13/2216394/www/popularhandbags.co.uk/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_product_product.php(490): ModelCatalogProduct->get in /srv/disk13/2216394/www/popularhandbags.co.uk/system/database/mysqli.php on line 40

What can i do to fix this issue?

Comment: It seems like the theme needs to create a table named oc_product_tab. Your are missing the table.

Comment: Can I creat a table by myself?

Comment: mabe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411499/open-cart-product-page-goes-blank-upon-theme-upload-vqmod-on

Comment: thank you, the problem was sorted accidentally , I simply clicked extra product tab, so the oc_prodcut_tab was automatically created in mysql